# Sentiment is looking at only 1 character at a time

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a sentiment analysis problem in twitter. My goal is to collect data in a csv file, in three columns based on the sentiment. It seems like the sentiment is looking at only 1 character at a time when it is supposed to look 1 tweet at a time.

Any help will be appreciated

```
    pos1, neg1, neu1 = 0, 0, 0
    header=['Positive','Negative','Neutral']

    #Create an empty csv file which has three headers: 'Positive','Negative','Neutral'
    with open('List.csv','w') as file:
        write=csv.DictWriter(file,fieldnames=header)
        write.writeheader()

  #doc for Stream Listener to tweepy: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html  

    class Listener(StreamListener):

        def on_data(self, data):
            raw_t=json.loads(data)

            data=raw_t['text']
            #four lines below will clear the tweets by removing: metions, has tag etc.
            data = re.sub('@[A-Za-z0–9]+', '',data) #Removing @mentions
            data = re.sub('#', '', data) # Removing '#' hash tag
            data = re.sub('RT[\s]+', '', data) # Removing RT
            data = re.sub('https?:\/\/\S+', '', data) # Removing hyperlink

            global pos1 
            global neg1 
            global neu1
            pos, neg, neu = 0, 0, 0

            for tweet in data:
                print(tweet)
                analysis = TextBlob(tweet)
                #print(analysis.sentiment)

                #the below if statement will count the number of tweets based on their sentiment('Positive','Negative','Neutral')
                if analysis.sentiment[0]>0:
                    pos+=1

                elif analysis.sentiment[0]<0:
                    neg+=1

                else:
                    neu+=1

            pos1=pos1+pos
            neg1=neg1+neg
            neu1=neu1+neu

            #write the result from counting to the csv file "List.csv"
            with open('List.csv', 'a') as file:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=header)
                info={
                    'Positive':pos1,
                    'Negative':neg1,
                    'Neutral':neu1
                      }
                writer.writerow(info)

            print(data)
            return True


        def on_error(self, status):
            print(status)


    l = Listener()
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['trump'])
```

Comment: is "data" a string?  If so, "for tweet in data" will just iterate through each character in that string.  Sounds like you want to pass all of "data" to the sentiment analysis, not just each character in data.  Remove the for loop.

Comment: @user2263572 thank you for your help!